# How can I alter the description of a link (with hash) shared on facebook

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to share a specific part of a page so I use a hashlink for example: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GMA_Network_radio_stations#References`

Facebook parses the `<p>` tag closest to the element with the linked id.

Is there a way to tell Facebook what it should use as description? Ideally I'd like to do this on an individual basis.

**UPDATE:** Since @Sturmeh suggests that I can post the link description via the API I'm enclosing the code that isn't working:

```
$statusUpdate = array(
  'link'      =>  $share_link,
  'message'   =>  $message,
  'description' => $description
);

//Post to Facebook
$facebook->api("/$user_id/feed", "post", $statusUpdate);
```

Comment: Are you talking about share tools, like ShareThis, etc?

Comment: no I'm using the facebook API actually, but it shouldn't really matter what tool you use as Facebook does the parsing itself...

Comment: I asked because if you were talking about these mentioned tools, you can define what thumbnail, title, description, etc, that should go with the shared link.

Comment: I don't think the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) has a method for doing this. Maybe you could find/create a url shortener service that allows you to create a page with custom open graph metadata, then use a js redirect to the final destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot be done via a "share" functionality or default "like" button, and here's the problem: You, from the server-side, cannot access the hashlink. If you could, you could manipulate the the `description` meta tag to reflect the hashlink. But, as i said, you cannot access the hash from the URL. So, your only option (if you want a "like" button on your site) is to implement a custom `like` button that will call the Graph API.

But from my understanding, you want a different description when a user "shares" that url on Facebook. Unfortunately, given the current restraints on server-side languages accessing that hashlink, it's not possible.

Comment: One way I think it can be done is by just having a hidden p element that contains facebook metadata, but I wonder if there is a way in which I can use facebook meta tags for each hashlink, since the metatags are just xml/html like the rest of the page...

Comment: No, that is not possible. Facebook will only grab the 1 meta tag description found in the `head` tag. It does not care about the `p` tag that the hashlink is meant to go to

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/

```
description: A description of the link (appears beneath the link caption)
```

The REST API does not support the description field, you should be posting to the feed connection of a user. (Using the Graph API)

To clarify:

According to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.post/), you should; use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) and POST a [Post object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user) to the feed connection of the [User object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user).

Comment: the feed connection? Please clarify

Comment: If you look [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.post/) (the legacy method) you can see how they describe it should be done up the top. (I updated the answer.)

Comment: I added an example of how I'm currently using the facebook sdk, I'm pretty sure that is using the Graph API as it is the latest version.

Comment: Actually on a second look I think it's only a readable attribute, which is quite odd. I hope you find an answer!

Comment: That's what I thought. You gave me hope but meh. What about metatags for hashlinks are you clued up on that?